# How can we send json encoded data through ajax via form text input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am fetching php json encoded data using ajax and then setting values to form input then sending it to other page . But json fetched values does not post to other page while normal input values are posting . Here's the code i am using . Your help will be highly appriciated . 
    `

```
if(isset($_POST['send_mail'])){

header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$out = array('a'=>"Volvo", 'b'=>"BMW", 'c'=>"Toyota");
echo json_encode($out);
//print_r($out);
exit();

}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function send_mail_test(){
var txt = $("#test_txt").val();

if( txt !=""){
$.ajax({
url : "chckvar.php",
type : "POST",
//async : false,
dataType: "JSON",
data : {
send_mail : 1,
txt_val : txt
},
success : function(data){

document.getElementById('code_r').setAttribute('value', data.a);

}    
});
 //return false;
}
else alert("please enter some text");
 //return false;

}
</script>
<form method="post" action="sub.php" name="myform" onSubmit="return send_mail_test()">
<input type="text" name="name"  id="test_txt">
<input type="text"  name="code_r" id="code_r">
<input type="submit" name="_mail" value="send" >
</form>`
```

**sub.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);

?>
```

**UPDATE**
I am using onclick on button in another form and trying to change action page from there and then submitting form to that action is that possible  ??

```
<script>
function action(){
var str = location.href;
 var x = "feedback.php?page="+str;
$("#quick_query").attr("action", x);
 $('#quick_query').submit();
}
</script>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
<input type="button" onclick="action()">
</form>
```

It is changing the action but doesn't submit the form ? how can i achieve it that will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSWER UPADTED:

The problem with your code is that the submit event occurs even before ajax is called. The following changes have been done in your code

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="sub.php" name="myform" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="name"  id="test_txt">
    <input type="text"  name="code_r" id="code_r">
    <input type="button" name="_mail" value="send" onclick="return send_mail_test()" >
</form>

    <br><hr><br>
<form method="post" action="xyz.php" name="anotherform" id="anotherform">
    <input type="button" name="change" value="Change action of above form" onclick="changeformaction();" >
</form>
```

The onsubmit on the form is removed & the submit button is changed to normal button. The send_mail_test() function is called on the Send button now.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    function send_mail_test() {
        var txt = $("#test_txt").val();
        if (txt != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url : "chckvar.php",
                type : "POST",
                //async : false,
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {
                    send_mail : 1,
                    txt_val : txt
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#code_r').val(data.a);
                    $('#myform').submit();
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert("please enter some text");
            return false;
        }
    }
function changeformaction(){
   $("#myform").prop('action','newaction.php');
   $('#myform').submit();
}
</script>
```

Here a small change is made in ajax success callback , after the response is received and the value is set in the input , the form is made to submit then.

No change is needed in your ajax file.

Comment: Could you help me a bit more see my update its urgent .

Comment: sure , i will like to , let me check your updated question and will try solving it

Comment: @Share fun - check my updated answer. I think this is what you wanted.

Comment: no their is no concern with previous form . I want the another form to be sent onclick its button through javascript

Comment: change the name of the function from action() to something else and your code should work.

Comment: thnxx you were really helpful :)

Comment: @Share fun - its my pleasure , if you think my above comment is helpful in solving your query and for this post , can you upvote it as well . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form[name="myform"]').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var txt = $(this).find("#test_txt").val();

        if (txt.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "chckvar.php",
                type: "POST",
                //async : false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    send_mail: 1,
                    txt_val: txt
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#code_r').attr('value', data.a); //$('#code_r').val(data.a);
                    $(this).submit()
                }
            });
        } else alert("please enter some text");


    });
});
</script>
<form method="post" action="sub.php" name="myform">
<input type="text" name="name"  id="test_txt">
<input type="text"  name="code_r" id="code_r">
<input type="submit" name="_mail" value="send" >
</form>
```

Comment: not working even if i left name empty it does not show alert @madalin ivascu